# AWS CDK cloudfront module seems like it doesn't work well

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I use AWS cli as below, it works.

> aws cloudfront create-distribution   --origin-domain-name  EcsTe-Farga-5AIKHC7TM127-1328201825.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com

I use AWS CloudFormation, it also works.

```
Resources:
  WebsiteCDN:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Enabled: 'true'
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: 'true'
          TargetOriginId: only-origin
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: allow-all
        Origins:
        - CustomOriginConfig:
            HTTPPort: '80'
            HTTPSPort: '443'
            OriginProtocolPolicy: http-only
          DomainName: 'EcsTe-Farga-5AIKHC7TM127-1328201825.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com'
          Id: only-origin
```

But when I wrote the CDK code as below, it doesn't work. Is there any code that I wrote wrong?

> 

```
export class Cf2 extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
            const distribution = new cloudfront.CloudFrontWebDistribution(this, 'SiteDistribution', {

              originConfigs: [
                  {
                      customOriginSource: {
                        domainName: 'EcsTe-Farga-5AIKHC7TM127-1328201825.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com'
                      },
                      behaviors: [{
                        isDefaultBehavior: true,
                        allowedMethods: cloudfront.CloudFrontAllowedMethods.ALL,
                      }]
                  }
              ]
          });
  }
}
```

Comment: For CDK is really new, so if some one can help to find the mistake in my code. Thankks.

Comment: Please detail what doesn't work... any error messages?

Comment: No error message, but when I goto  d2daik8yhrbr9i.cloudfront.net (cloudfront) , it shows ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Comment: The cdk formal example shows how to use the S3OriginSource, but when I change to customOriginSource, it went wrong. I have setup several CloudFrontWebDistribution, the result is just the same.